# Understanding dynamic allocation in this input, c

Tags: c, arrays

Suppose I want to input a square of integers. On each line, each pair of integers is separated by a space. So the following code works just fine :

```
//size of the square
int N;
scanf("%d",&N);
int **c;
c = malloc(N*sizeof(int*));

for (i=0;i<N;i++)
{   c[i] = malloc(2*sizeof(int));
    for (j=0;j<2;j++)
    {scanf("%d",&c[i][j]);}
}
```

So here I don't understand why space are not taken into account (so why it is working :-)) ? On the contrary, if I used a n array c[N][N], it wouldn't have worked, because each space would have been interpreted as an input of the array

Comment: You can write as many numbers on a line as you like from 0 to N*N and scanf won't care; it looks for white space (including newlines) followed by digits.  Of course, a non-digit locks the whole thing up; you should test that `scanf()` works fully each time you call it: `if (scanf("%d", &c[i][j]) != 1) { ...process error... }`.  Consider the merits of using `fgets()` to read a line and `sscanf()` to parse it; error reporting is a _lot_ easier!

Comment: It appears that your code is reading an N row x 2 column matrix, not a square matrix.  Unless you're stuck with a C89 compiler (or a C11 compiler that predefines `__STDC_NO_VLA__`), you would be able to write: `int c[N][2];` in place of `int **c;`, and you would not then need the `malloc()` statements (assuming you only use the matrix in this function, or in functions called from this function).  If you want to pass the matrix back to the calling code, you get into some interesting issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int N;
scanf("%d",&N);
int c[N][N];   /* Error */
```

The size of `c[][]` must be known when it is created. That means that N cannot be obtained dynamically from input.

**Edit:**
As pointed out by Jonathan Leffler, some compilers support array size being determined at run-time. It was part of the C99 standard, but in the subsequent C11 standard it was made optional.

While optional features may be great, they reduce the portability of your program.

Comment: This is not true in C99.  It is also not true when `c` is an `int **` as in the code in the question.  This answer should not be the selected one.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't understand the question?

Comment: Maybe I don't understand the question, but the statement that 'int c[N][N];` would not work is inaccurate for modern C compilers (those that support the old version of the standard, C99, or the new version of the standard, C11 — subject to `__STDC_NO_VLA__` not being predefined). Only archaic C compilers that are either pre-standard or that only support C89 that won't accpet `int c[N][N];`, with `N` being determined at run-time. This is a VLA; it is standard C. Therefore, your comment is incomplete, though it may be accurate for the OP's C compiler (which is not identified, but might be MSVC).

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically, each invocation of scanf is going to be white-space delimited.

Comment: yes but why declaring instead c[N][N], and then "scanf("%d",&c[i][j]);" wouldn't have worked ?

Comment: 1) did you malloc `c[i] = malloc(N*sizeof(int))` instead of 2?  2) did the user actually input n items into the row?  You don't have any error handling so I pretty much need to see the test input as well.